# I am trying to pull a list of download links from firebase storage to display in my react/nextjs component

Tags: javascript, pdf, next.js, firebase-storage

when trying to pull the array the data is always empty. Anyone have any ideas where i am going wrong?
I checked in the console and as far as i can tell there is a reference to firebase storage, but there is no data. But i there are 4 documents in the storage that should be outputting URL links.
this is my component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// i'm initializing firebase with firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
import { projectStorage } from '@/firebaseConfig'; 
 // projectStorage is =         firebase.storage();


const PDFViewer = () => {
  const [pdfUrls, setPdfUrls] = useState();

  useEffect(()=>{
   const storageRef = projectStorage.ref();
   const pdfRef = storageRef.child('myfirebaselocationpath/uploadeddocs/'); 
   const urls = [];
   pdfRef.listAll().then((result) => {
    result.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
    itemRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      urls.push(url);
    });
  });
  setPdfUrls(urls);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error retrieving PDF files:', error);
});
},[])
console.log(pdfUrls)
/*  console.log( pdfUrls.map((url) => {
return url
 })
) */
return (
<div>
  <h1>PDF Viewer</h1>
  {pdfUrls.map((url) => (
    <iframe key={url} src={url} width="100%" height="600px" />
  ))}
</div>
 );
};

export default PDFViewer;`
```

The above component is what i tried and was expecting a list of links to be mapped, but got no data displayed. and the pdfUrls is always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
pdfRef.listAll().then((result) => {
  result.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
  itemRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
    urls.push(url);
  });
});
setPdfUrls(urls);
```

Both `listAll` and `getDownloadURL` are asynchronous operations that may take some time to complete. Instead of blocking the entire script, the main code continues while the operations happen - and then your callback blocks get executed when the data (the list of files, or the download URL) is available.

That means that your `setPdfUrls(urls);` runs before any of the `urls.push(url);` has run, and this sets an empty list. I recommend checking this in a debugger, or by adding some logging.

---

The simplest way to solve the problem is to move the `setPdfUrls(urls);` **into** the inner callback:

```
pdfRef.listAll().then((result) => {
  result.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
  itemRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
    urls.push(url);
    setPdfUrls(urls);
  });
});
```

Now it will call after each download URL is determined. This performs multiple updates, so it may cause some flashing in your UI, but the data should show up now.

---

To only make one call to `setPdfUrls(urls);` while waiting for everything to finish takes a bit more work. The easiest way to do this is probably to mark your entire `useEffect` handler as `async` and use `await` inside it:

```
useEffect(() => async {
  const storageRef = projectStorage.ref();
  const pdfRef = storageRef.child('myfirebaselocationpath/uploadeddocs/');
  const urls = [];
  const result = await pdfRef.listAll();
  for (const itemRef of result.items) {
    const url = await itemRef.getDownloadURL();
    urls.push(url);
  }
  setPdfUrls(urls);
}, [])
```

So this code:

- Uses `await` to ensure the asynchronous operations complete before we call `setPdfUrls`.
- Uses a `for...of` loop to ensure we can use `await` inside that loop.